# React: How to direct new page

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am beginner in React js.  I am developing projects about getting pokemons with API from pokeApi. I was able to get all pokemons(name,id, and image) from there. However I want to get more detail.  When I click one pokemon I want to see more detail about it.

This is my PokemonCard.js

```
 <Router>    
    <StyledLink to={`pokemon/${this.state.pokemonIndex}`}>
        <Card className="card">
         <h5 className="card-header">{this.state.pokemonIndex}</h5>
           .
           .
           .
       </Card>
  </StyledLink>
</Router>
```

When I click one pokemon the url changes from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:3000/pokemon/7. However, nothing shows up.

this is my Pokemon.js

```
    import axios from 'axios';
    import React, { Component } from 'react'

  export default class Pokemon extends Component {

 state = {
    name: '',
    pokemonIndex: '',
    imageUrl: ''
};

async componentDidMount() {
    const { pokemonIndex } = this.props.match.params;

    // Urls for pokemon information
    const pokemonUrl = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokemonIndex}/`;
    const pokemonSpeciesUrl = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-species/${pokemonIndex}/`;

    //get information about pocekoms

    const pokemonRes = await axios.get(pokemonUrl);
    const name = pokemonRes.data.name;
    this.setState({name})
}
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{this.state.name}</h1>
        </div>
    )
 }
```

}

What did I wrong? Please explain to me. I am beginner in this language. Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Where are you rendering the `Link` to go to a new page? Can you also share how you're rendering the `Route` components? It also sort of looks like you've a `Router` wrapping the card, you probably don't want this there. You only need a single `Router` wrapping your app.

Comment: When I did without router, I got error it says you should not use <Link> outside a <Router>. To prevent that, I added that. I have no idea purpose of it honestly.

Comment: @DrewReese.  here <StyledLink to={`pokemon/${this.state.pokemonIndex}`}>, I am rendering the link. I guess

Comment: You need the Router, but not in this file, just wrapping your app. And the Switch Route...

Comment: I see. Is `PokemonCard` your root app container, or near it? Where are you rendering your routes? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example My guess was that each `PokemonCard` was mapped from *some* state higher up in the ReactTree. You need only one `Router` and it typically wraps your entire app container. This is so you provide one single routing context to the entire app so all links, routes, etc... reference the same routing context.

Comment: in App.js. This is my project. İf you have time please check it. I will appreciate it. https://github.com/yasoyase/pokemon

Comment: Place the router in app.js instead, and also the different routes for the app. The pokemon card should only have the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issues

1. You are wrapping each `PokemonCard` with it's own `Router`, you need only 1 single `Router` wrapping the entire app.
2. You've not any `Route` components rendering the UI.

## Solution

index.js - Import a `Router` and wrap the app.

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router>
      <App />
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

App.js - Render the UI components into `Route` components within a `Switch` so only a single route is rendered at-a-time.

```
...
import { Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Pokemon from "./components/pokemon/Pokemon";
...

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <NavBar />
      <div className="container">
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/pokemon/:pokemonIndex" component={Pokemon} />
          <Route path="/">
            <Dashboard />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

PokemonCard.js - Remove the extraneous `Router` components.

```
...
render() {
  return (
    <div className="col-md-3 col-sm-6 mb-5">
      <StyledLink to={`pokemon/${this.state.pokemonIndex}`}>
        <Card className="card">
          ...
        </Card>
      </StyledLink>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit react-how-to-direct-new-page]

Comment: It works.  Thanks a lot. I have one more question. When I click one pokemon. The url goes like this: localhost:3000/pokeman/4. After that When I clicked another one the pokeman/5 added the previous url. is it because of the  issue 1 that you mentioned?

Comment: @sadbird Possibly? If you've done what I have then there shouldn't be any way to click to a new pokemon without first navigating back to the dashboard.

Comment: I did exactly what you did.   no problems. I just wondered  it.  Thank you so much  for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing Route with the routes you want your component to be rendered

```js
<Switch>
          <Route exact path="pokemon/:id">
            <Home />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/about">
            <About />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/dashboard">
            <Dashboard />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is more of a comment than it is an answer.